# `int` assumed to always be 32 bit in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

It appears that in OpenCV, the `int` datatype is always assumed to be 32 bits. This is reflected in the documentation (for example, [in the introduction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#fixed-pixel-types-limited-use-of-templates)), and also in the source code (for example, in the comments of `modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h`, and the fact that it defines `uint` to be a 32-bit unsigned integer, but doesn't define a corresponding signed type).

How does this not break OpenCV on systems in which `int` isn't 32 bits? Afterall, `int` is only guaranteed to be 16 bits by the standard.

I would have expected OpenCV to define datatypes for all sizes that it uses (just like it does for `int64`), or use `uint_8` and friends.

Comment: While of course the primitive data types may vary across platforms, I believe that `int` is 4 bytes on most that you are likely to care about. For instance, [this page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os) describes the variation of `long` in the Intel compiler, but says "The size of the "int" integer type is 4 bytes ... for all the above combinations of operating system and architecture." It is also 4 bytes in the [MS compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: In fact, see section 3 of [Agner Fog's calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf). It is 4 on basically everything interesting.

Comment: @BoBTFish: an x86-specific guide isn't the best source for that claim, though :)

Answer (score 1):

> How does this not break OpenCV on systems in which int isn't 32 bits?

Probably, yes. You should try building on such a system to be sure. Then again, I wish you good luck finding such a system that still has enough memory and CPU power to do meaningful computer vision; 16-bit `int` is typically found on very small embedded systems these days.

The clean way to get a fast type of at least 32 bits wide is to use the `int_fast32_t` type from `<stdint.h>`, but this requires C99 support and Microsoft's C compiler has long not supported that standard.